# How to keep latest version of cloudbuild.yaml seperate in the cloud storage

Tags: google-app-engine, pipeline, google-cloud-build

My `cloudbuild.yaml` consists of:

```
steps:
  - name: maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-slim

    entrypoint: 'mvn'
    args: ["clean","install","-PgenericApiSuite","-pl", "api-testing", "-am", "-B"]

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    args: ['-m', 'cp', '-r', '/workspace/api-testing/target/cucumber-html-reports', 'gs://testing-reports/$BUILD_ID']
```

But every time it runs now my bucket shows the reports with its `build_id`.

Is there a way I can keep the latest report separate from the rest?

Comment: What do you mean by "separate"? In another bucket than older reports?

Comment: no, I mean as a way to recognize the latest report.
If I create a new folder "latest" and I deploy my build, the older report in the folder doesn't get overwritten. So I have no idea how to put the latest report in a seperate folder.

Comment: What do you want the resulting bucket to look like?  What should the "name" of he latest report be?  What about including the data/time in the report file name?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want, my bucket looks like this rite now:
https://imgur.com/mITJxS1

the name of the folder is the BUILD_ID but I want a folder /latest where only the latest report is stored. If I change the dir to /latest the files in this folder are not overwritten so its still an old report. Adding a timestamp is a nice visual solution but eventually I want to automatically use the latest report to create a static website

Comment: so I want to refer to that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly symbolic link doesn't exist in Cloud Storage. For achieving what you want, you have to handle this manually with these 2 steps at the end of your job:

```
# delete the previous existing latest directory
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    args: ['-m', 'rm', '-r', 'gs://testing-reports/latest']

# copy the most recent file into the latest directory
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    args: ['-m', 'cp', '-r', 'gs://testing-reports/$BUILD_ID', 'gs://testing-reports/latest']
```